# How to redirect rejected rows to another file?

Tags: csv, vbscript

This is my Source `csv` file

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
1,A,AA,X,Y,H
2,B,,,CC,D, -- reject this row because (CC)it should be in col3
3,E,FF,Y,L
4,G,,,XX,P,B -- reject this row because(XX) it should be in col3
5,P,Kk,,,D,M -- this is correct record since kk 2 letter digit is in col3
6,G,MM,,,,-- correct record since record MM is in col3
```

How do I validate this csv file?

so that I get all `2` letter in `column 3` [col3]

I am following these steps source file to be copied into another file(since I don't operate in source file) then

I am not getting how to put the rejected rows into another file ,please can somebody help me on this!

```
Sub test()

    '///OPEN FILE and READ
    Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\coe.txt", 1)
    'Set objFileToWrite = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\copyme2.txt", 2)
    strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
    objFileToRead.Close


    ' ///PASTE
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFileToWrite = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\cou.txt", 2)
    objFileToWrite.Write strFileText
    objFileToWrite.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Please if somebody could help me on this ! I am very new using Vb script !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are new to VBScript, you should start your coding with a plan (the main task, the subtasks, the ideas to solve each task) and a skeleton .vbs that makes it easy to experiment with the methods used to solve the (sub)tasks.

In your case the main task is to "filter bad lines in a source file to a destination file". This task is solved if you can "read the lines of the source file", "recognize the bad ones", and "write them to the destination file".

The default way to read a file's lines is:

```
  Dim tsIn : Set tsIn = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\21755767.csv")
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
     Dim sLine : sLine = tsIn.ReadLine()
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
```

"default" means: You must have very good/specific reasons **not** to choose this idiom (e.g.: using .ReadAll() on a short file for in-place-editing or debug-display) or to deviate from it (e.g.: you can't rely on .OpenTextFile's default arguments if your file is UTF-16 encoded). For some atrocities - e.g.

```
  Do While Not tsIn.AtEndOfStream = "False"
```

there is no excuse at all.

Writing (some) lines to another file should look like this:

```
  Dim tsOut : Set tsOut = goFS.CreateTextFile("..\data\21755767-bads.csv")
  Dim tsIn  : Set tsIn  = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\21755767.csv")
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
     Dim sLine : sLine = tsIn.ReadLine()
     If True Then
        tsOut.WriteLine sLine
     End If
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
  tsOut.Close
```

Using .CreateTextFile(JustTheFileSpec) instead of .OpenTextFile(lots, of, other, args) is the most simple/clear/error-save approach for the standard case: new (perhaps empty) destination file for each run of the script.

As mentioned above, appending a

```
  WScript.Echo  goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\21755767-bads.csv").ReadAll()
```

for display is ok.

The idea for the filter subtask is based on the observations:

1. the header line contains the correct number of fields/commas
2. the offending lines contain a bad number of commas

Then it's easy to combine the results of the work above into:

```
  Dim tsOut   : Set tsOut = goFS.CreateTextFile("..\data\21755767-bads.csv")
  Dim tsIn    : Set tsIn  = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\21755767.csv")
  Dim sLine   : sLine     = tsIn.ReadLine()
  Dim nUBSeps : nUBSeps   = UBound(Split(sLine, ","))
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
     sLine = tsIn.ReadLine()
     If nUBSeps <> UBound(Split(sLine, ",")) Then
        tsOut.WriteLine sLine
     End If
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
  tsOut.Close
```

The full script:

```
Option Explicit ' (1)

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") ' (2)

WScript.Quit demoReadFile() ' (3)
WScript.Quit demoReadWriteFile()
WScript.Quit demoFilterBads()

Function demoReadFile() ' (4)
  demoReadFile = 0
  Dim tsIn : Set tsIn = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\21755767.csv")
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
     Dim sLine : sLine = tsIn.ReadLine()
     WScript.Echo tsIn.Line - 1, sLine
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
End Function

Function demoReadWriteFile() ' (5)
  demoReadWriteFile = 0
  Dim tsOut : Set tsOut = goFS.CreateTextFile("..\data\21755767-bads.csv")
  Dim tsIn  : Set tsIn  = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\21755767.csv")
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
     Dim sLine : sLine = tsIn.ReadLine()
     If True Then
        tsOut.WriteLine sLine
     End If
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
  tsOut.Close
  WScript.Echo  goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\21755767-bads.csv").ReadAll()
End Function

Function demoFilterBads() ' (6)
  demoFilterBads = 0
  Dim tsOut   : Set tsOut = goFS.CreateTextFile("..\data\21755767-bads.csv")
  Dim tsIn    : Set tsIn  = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\21755767.csv")
  Dim sLine   : sLine     = tsIn.ReadLine()
  Dim nUBSeps : nUBSeps   = UBound(Split(sLine, ","))
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
     sLine = tsIn.ReadLine()
     If nUBSeps <> UBound(Split(sLine, ",")) Then
        tsOut.WriteLine sLine
     End If
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
  tsOut.Close
  WScript.Echo  goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\21755767-bads.csv").ReadAll()
End Function
```

sample output:

demoReadFile()

```
cscript 21755767.vbs
1 col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
2 1,A,AA,X,Y
3 2,B,,,CC,D
4 3,E,FF,Y,
5 4,G,,,XX,P
```

demoFilterBads()

```
cscript 21755767.vbs
2,B,,,CC,D
4,G,,,XX,P
```

Such a script could start from a skeleton/template like:

```
Option Explicit ' (1)

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") ' (2)

WScript.Quit step00() ' (3)
WScript.Quit step01()

...

Function step00() ' (4)
  step00 = 0
  ...
End Function
```

1. All your scripts should start with "Option Explicit" to guard against mis-spelled variable names
2. If you allow global variables at all, then goFS is a good candidate. If not, create just one FSO and pass it to the Subs/Functions/Methods that need it. **Never** create a new FSO each time you need its methods/properties.
3. Use comments or reordering to call the function you currently work with
4. 'sample' function; write a lot of them to check/elaborate your ideas

**Update wrt comment:**

Add an utility function:

```
Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function
```

and an experiment/explore function:

```
Function demoFilterSteps()
  demoFilterSteps = 0
  Dim sLine
  For Each sLine In Split("col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 1,A,AA,X,Y 2,B,,,CC,D")
      WScript.Echo 0, qq(sLine)
      Dim aParts  : aParts  = Split(sLine, ",")
      Dim nUBSeps : nUBSeps = UBound(aParts)
      WScript.Echo 1, nUBSeps, qq(Join(aParts, "-"))

      WScript.Echo
  Next
  nUBSeps = 4            ' correct
  sLine   = "2,B,,,CC,D" ' bad
  Dim sExpr : sExpr = "nUBSeps <> UBound(Split(sLine, "",""))"
  WScript.Echo 2, nUBSeps, qq(sLine), sExpr, CStr(Eval(sExpr))
End Function
```

output:

```
cscript 21755767.vbs
0 "col1,col2,col3,col4,col5"
1 4 "col1-col2-col3-col4-col5"

0 "1,A,AA,X,Y"
1 4 "1-A-AA-X-Y"

0 "2,B,,,CC,D"
1 5 "2-B---CC-D"

2 4 "2,B,,,CC,D" nUBSeps <> UBound(Split(sLine, ",")) True
```

To see

1. Splitting the header line results in a nUBSeps of 4 (4 separators between 5 fields)
2. A good line results in a nUBSeps of 4 too - not a surprise
3. A bad line gives a nUBSeps different (<>) of 4; 5 in this sample
4. Assuming nUBSeps is 4 (correct), the expression `nUBSeps <> UBound(Split(sLine, ","))` evaluates to True, when sLine holds a bad line - so that line should be written to the destination file

Comment: @user2841280 - what exactly don't you understand? Did you look at the VBScript Docs - especially for Split() and UBound()?

Comment: sir! once the bad recoreds are deleted I want to correct them and put them back! like `2,B,,,CC,D
4,G,,,XX,P` I need to remove the extra `,` and put them in order,can you pls help me I treid using regex but not quite getting it?

Comment: [Please do you mind checking this? sorry for commenting here !](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796109/data-validation)