# Read data from ini file

Tags: vbscript, ini

i have a vbscript that takes input file name

the code is

```
 Dim tsout: Set tsout = gofs.CreateTextFile("C:\....csv")
 Dim tsin: Set tsin = gofs.OpenTextFile("C:\.....csv")
```

how can i configure this so that path `createTextFile(....)` is read from config file(`.ini`)

the file path for creating and writing output-to, must be taken from `ini` file

this is my ini file

// my ini file

```
[Read_file]
tsout=E:.....tt.csv
tsin=E:\....gt.csv

    [col]
Number1=4
Number2=5
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple version of an .ini file parser:

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'WScript.Quit demoReadFile()
WScript.Quit demoReadIniFile()

Function demoReadFile()
  demoReadFile = 0
  Dim tsIn : Set tsIn = goFS.OpenTextFile(".\21825192.ini")
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
     Dim sLine : sLine = tsIn.ReadLine()
     WScript.Echo tsIn.Line - 1, sLine
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
End Function

Function demoReadIniFile()
  demoReadIniFile = 0
  Dim dicIni : Set dicIni = ReadIniFile(".\21825192.ini")
  Dim sSec, sKV
  For Each sSec In dicIni.Keys()
      WScript.Echo "---", sSec
      For Each sKV In dicIni(sSec).Keys()
          WScript.Echo " ", sKV, "=>", dicIni(sSec)(sKV)
      Next
  Next
  WScript.Echo dicIni("tsout")("Path")
End Function

Function ReadIniFile(sFSpec)
  Dim dicTmp : Set dicTmp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim tsIn   : Set tsIn   = goFS.OpenTextFile(sFSpec)
  Dim sLine, sSec, aKV
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
     sLine = Trim(tsIn.ReadLine())
     If "[" = Left(sLine, 1) Then
        sSec = Mid(sLine, 2, Len(sLine) - 2)
        Set dicTmp(sSEc) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     Else
        If "" <> sLine Then
           aKV = Split(sLine, "=")
           If 1 = UBound(aKV) Then
              dicTmp(sSec)(Trim(aKV(0))) = Trim(aKV(1))
           End If
        End If
     End If
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
  Set ReadIniFile = dicTmp
End Function
```

output:

```
cscript 21825192.vbs
1 [pipapo]
2 Path=E:\dont\find\me.csv
3   Some  = thing else
4
5 [tsout]
6 Path=E:\where\ever\output.csv
7 abc=def

cscript 21825192.vbs
--- pipapo
  Path => E:\dont\find\me.csv
  Some => thing else
--- tsout
  Path => E:\where\ever\output.csv
  abc => def
E:\where\ever\output.csv
```

(see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21758109/603855) for background)

**Update wrt comment/edit:**

I added your sections to my sample .ini file:

```
type 21825192.ini
[pipapo]
Path=E:\dont\find\me.csv
  Some  = thing else

[tsout]
Path=E:\where\ever\output.csv
abc=def

[Read_file]
tsout=E:.....tt.csv
tsin=E:\....gt.csv

    [col]
Number1=4
Number2=5
```

and - just for clarity - changed the final output line of my demoReadIniFile() function to:

```
  WScript.Echo "tsout.Path", dicIni("tsout")("Path")
  WScript.Echo "Read_file.tsin", dicIni("Read_file")("tsin")
  WScript.Echo "col.Number2", dicIni("col")("Number2")
```

The output:

```
cscript 21825192.vbs
--- pipapo
  Path => E:\dont\find\me.csv
  Some => thing else
--- tsout
  Path => E:\where\ever\output.csv
  abc => def
--- Read_file
  tsout => E:.....tt.csv
  tsin => E:\....gt.csv
--- col
  Number1 => 4
  Number2 => 5
tsout.Path E:\where\ever\output.csv
Read_file.tsin E:\....gt.csv
col.Number2 5
```

So I don't understand at all why accessing 'the col section taking out number1=4 and Number2=5' causes any problems.

Comment: This worked GREAT for me! One thing worth noting (might save somebody some headaches):  This will have problems if you use tabs instead of spaces in your .ini file.  Use spaces, or nothing at all, between the key name and the equal sign.

Comment: Note: the above ReadIniFile() function doesn't quite correlate with the way PHP reads them. The above will read beyond a semicolon, where PHP reads that as the beginning of a comment to be ignored. PHP will take an entire string including a semicolon if it's wrapped in quotes; but ASP will read the quote marks themselves as part of the value..

Comment: Searching for the ini file parser I've found that many parsers has multiple issues: can not retain comments, can not retain initial formatting, rereads/reparses entire file each time when accessing a single key/value, etc. This parser has having at least 2 issues, which means you can't use it for an external application configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

VBS do not support IniFile class. You need to create own parser of INI file. Other solution (also with creating own parsing functions, but much easy than to parse INI file): save TAB delimited data, for example: first comming OUTgoing file, than TAB char, than INcomming file.

Answer (score 0):

Ekkehard's demo tweaked for Classic ASP:

```
Function demoReadIniFile()
  demoReadIniFile = 0
  Dim dicIni : Set dicIni = ReadIniFile("c:\path\to\21825192.ini")
  Dim sSec, sKV
  For Each sSec In dicIni.Keys()
      response.write "---" & sSec & "<br>"
      For Each sKV In dicIni(sSec).Keys()
          response.write " " & sKV & " => " & dicIni(sSec)(sKV) & "<br>"
      Next
  Next
'  response.write dicIni("tsout")("Path") & "<br>"
End Function
```

His ReadIniFile() works as written.