# need to have a vb script that replaces one line on four text files and then outputs them to a new file name

Tags: vbscript

I need a VBScript that will read & replace text in 4 separate text files and save it as different file names. I also want it to ask me what I want to replace the text with. the only text I need to replace is the 6 digits after the two letters under LUName, on each text file. the 6 digits resemble assets and are different on each. below is the 4 separate text files.

I have searched every where for a script that can do this and all the ones that I have found I am having issues with. I might add that I'm kind of familiar to programming in VBS and will have some issue understanding some things as I'm still learning.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that the purpose of this site is to assist people with their code and as such, we won't write code for you. So please share your attempts to get this working, and we will see what we can do to help.

Comment: See [Read data from ini file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825192/read-data-from-ini-file) for one implementation of doing this with VBA. That should give you a starting point.

Comment: well I am now giving up on this problem. thanks for any and all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading up on GetPrivateProfileString and it's partner, WritePrivateProfileString.  They are the Windows way to interact with an ini file, which is what you have posted here.

Then you might want to look at this article: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=5390

Comment: well I have another idea.... is there a script that would allow me to write this information to a text file? instead of already having the test files already written? and how would I do that in vbs? kid of in the way a program would write to a log.